# extract NAL units bitstream from an MP4 video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is it possible to extract every NAL units bitstream? (the actual bitstream)

for example extract them like this:

(4byte length + the remaining bytes till the end of the unit) and do this for all the units in a MP4 video? actually i want to check the occurrence of the 2 bytes after the 4byte length in a MP4 video (coded with H.264 codec).
can i use FFmpeg for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just do 'ffmpeg -I my.mp4 -an -vcodec copy out.264' then look for start codes in the resulting stream.

Comment: Do we have start codes now  0x000001 or 0x00000001? is the two bytes after four byte length same as 2 bytes after these start codes?and can i use ffmpeg again to find these start codes and save eachNAL units?cause i need the occurrence of those 2 bytes.

Comment: Start codes can be 3 or 4 bytes. No, ffmpeg will create a file per nal . But it's easy to write a program to do that.

Comment: How can i create a file per NAL?

Comment: Write a program. (This a web site for programmers after all)

Comment: I see i thought ffmpeg will do that. and the last questions we have video stream after start codes right? the two bytes after four byte length is same as 2 bytes after start codes?

Comment: A nalu is a nalu.